# Update number form field

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

I have a field named 'starting_price' in my table where I store money. I store money as an integer in cents and when i store it I multiply it with 100 so it can be stored in cents. For example, 10$ is stored as 1000 in database but when rendering it I divide it with 100 and also use number_format in twig. Now I want to add update functionality and I want to divide it with 100 before rendering it but it doesn't work. I have this in my form:

```
        ->add('starting_price', NumberType::class,[
        'label' => 'Starting price',
    ])
```

and this in my twig:

```
  {{ form_row(form.starting_price) }}
```

When I add `/100` in my twig file it returns an error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: A non-numeric value encountered").

[image: starting price form field]

This shows 12000 cents and I want it to show 120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Form Data Transformer: [Doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

```
$builder
    ->get(
        'starting_price',
        NumberType::class,
        [
            'label' => 'Starting price',
        ]
    )
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($data) {
            return $data / 100;
        },
        function ($data) {
            return $data * 100;
        }
   )
);
```